# Switching Between 3 Cameras

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to switch between 3 camera modes using a Switch on Int node but the camera gets stuck and doesn't cycle between all three modes. What am I doing wrong ?

Dev WS: Unreal Engine 5.1 on Windows

[image: problem]

Comment: Just from seeing the screenshot: You are not providing a different value to your `Switch on Int` node. Switch on int is a [`switch`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/FlowControl/Switch/SwitchonInt/) expression that requires an integer parameter passed in. You always pass in 0. You need to update that value.

Answer (score 2):

`Switch` node uses index which you provide as int to execute.
On your screen you have set default 0.
It means that every switch will do only first(0) one pin, because you have 0.
According to context, I understand you want to switch your camera successively?
Like: 1st one, 2nd one, 3rd one.
If yes, you should use [`MultiGate`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/UserGuide/FlowControl/#multigate) node.
It will increment the index of the execution, starting from exec 0 until it reached the last exec index.

Good luck! :)